# How to get the VShipTermsID from a vendor location record when you are in PO Entry?

Tags: acumatica

Our customer is requiring us to add a Shipping Terms field to the [PO Entry Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQlVS.jpg). Looking at the source code it appears that the Ship Via field is set in the POOrder_VendorLocaition_FieldUpdated event.

```
    protected virtual void POOrder_VendorLocationID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Location current = (Location)this.location.Current;
        POOrder row = (POOrder)e.Row;
        if (current == null || (current.BAccountID != row.VendorID || current.LocationID != row.VendorLocationID))
        {
            current = this.location.Select();
            this.location.Current = current;
        }
        ...
        sender.SetDefaultExt<POOrder.shipVia>(e.Row);
        ...
    }
```

When I create a POOrderEntry_Extension and write a POOrder_VendorLocation_FieldUpdated event (without the sender.SetDefaultExt line it fails validation with:

\App_RuntimeCode\POOrderEntry.cs(38): error CS1061: 'PX.Objects.PO.POOrderEntry_Extension' does not contain a definition for 'location' and no extension method 'location' accepting a first argument of type 'PX.Objects.PO.POOrderEntry_Extension' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I think once I can lookup the VShipTermsID field I can set my UsrVShipTermsID field in the PO.  I've tried to search for the appropriate using directive and have tried to step my way into the vendor record and then the location record. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the DAC Extension for the UsrVShipTermsID field.

```
[PXDBString(10)]
[PXSelector(typeof(
   Search<ShipTerms.shipTermsID>),
   DescriptionField = typeof(ShipTerms.description))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Shipping Terms")]
```

And here is the full POOrderEntry_Extension

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using PX.Common;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.TX;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using PX.Objects.AP;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects.SO;
using PX.TM;
using SOOrder = PX.Objects.SO.SOOrder;
using SOLine = PX.Objects.SO.SOLine;
using PX.CS.Contracts.Interfaces;
using PX.Data.DependencyInjection;
using PX.LicensePolicy;
using PX.Objects.PM;
using CRLocation = PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location;
using PX.Objects.AP.MigrationMode;
using PX.Objects.Common;
using PX.Objects.Common.Discount;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.PO;
using PX.Objects.AP.Locations;

namespace PX.Objects.PO
{
  public class POOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<POOrderEntry>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
    protected virtual void POOrder_VendorLocationID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
      Location current = (Location)Base.location.Current;
      POOrder row = (POOrder)e.Row;
      if (current == null || (current.BAccountID != row.VendorID || current.LocationID != row.VendorLocationID))
      {
        current = this.location.Select();
        this.location.Current = current;
      }
      //sender.SetDefaultExt<POOrder.shipVia>(e.Row);
    }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

Originally I was going to step my way from the PO to the Vendor to the location but I got lost when I tried to find the location record.  Has the same using directives.

```
protected virtual void POOrder_VendorID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
  var row = e.Row as POOrder;
  if (row.VendorID != null)
  {
    var vendor = PXSelectorAttribute.Select<POOrder.vendorID>(sender, row) as BAccount;
    if (vendor != null)
    {
      //var poorderExt = row.GetExtension<POOrderExt>();
      //poorderExt.UsrVShipTermsID = vendor.VShipTermsID;
      //sender.SetDefaultExt<POOrderExt.usrVShipTermsID>(e.Row);
      //sender.SetValueExt<POOrderExt.usrVShipTermsID>(row, VendorClass.shipTermsID);
      //poorderExt.UsrVShipTermsID = VendorClass.vendor.GetValue<VendorClass.shipTermsID>(VendorClass.vendor);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include you graph extension code? Seems like an issue with how it's setup.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague provided the answer.

```
protected void POOrder_VendorLocationID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
  POOrder row = (POOrder)e.Row;
  if (row == null) 
    return;
  POOrderExt rowExt = PXCache<POOrder>.GetExtension<POOrderExt>(row);
  {
    //retrieve LocVend Data
    LocationExtAddress location = PXSelect<LocationExtAddress,
       Where<LocationExtAddress.bAccountID, Equal<Current<POOrder.vendorID>>,
       And<LocationExtAddress.locationID, Equal<Current<POOrder.vendorLocationID>>>>>.Select(Base, row);
    rowExt.UsrVShipTermsID = location.VShipTermsID;
  }
}
```

Thanks for the support and help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access a property or method of the base Graph from an extension, use Base rather than this. For example, the line of code that is in the base graph

```
Location current = (Location)this.location.Current;
```

would be

```
Location current = (Location)Base.location.Current;
```

in the graph extension.

Comment: When I change this to Base I get the following error:  \App_RuntimeCode\POOrderEntry.cs(30): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Locations' does not exist in the namespace 'PX.Objects.AP' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: What is the line that is throwing the error? Can you update your code? Typically, classes are singular in Acumatica, and that error looks like you are referring to a class/type.